# TableLayout not showing after adding a LinearLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, addition, tablelayout

Everything was showing ok until i added the @+id/secondLayout. Suddenly, after adding it, the tablelayout no longer shows.
Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
    <Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chrono"
    android:textColor="#4169E1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chronometer"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/chrono"
>

</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: and what is Chronometer?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin it is an Android widget to show a chronometer...
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html

Comment: I think that you have a duplication of id.. make sure it is unique..

Answer (score 0):

Use `LinearLayout` and `TableLayout` height to `"wrap_content"`,because child `LinearLayout` took space of parent layout.so `tablelayout` not showing.
 i.e. Try this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
    <Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chrono"
    android:textColor="#4169E1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chronometer"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_below="@id/chrono"` has no effect in `LinearLayout` as it is used in `RelativeLayout`.
Give weight to your `TableLayout` as 1 and also change your  `android:layout_height` to `"wrap_content"`
Try following data :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/chrono"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chronometer"
            android:textColor="#4169E1"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#123456"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change **Chronometer** height to wrap_content

Try to Use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Chronometer
            android:id="@+id/chrono"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chronometer"
            android:textColor="#4169E1"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/chrono" >
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```